# how to delete singleton object

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

Assuming this implementation of a singleton pattern ( of course we should avoid Singleton: it is just question), I have just been thinking about static object being created. It is created on heap by a `new` operator, sure, but how is this destroyed? In following example we have a leak, so **how one should implement deletion of static singleton object**? Should there be a `please_delete()` public interface adopted, so one can call `myC->please_delete()` or is there other way to achieve this?

```
class CC{
public:
    static CC* cObj(){
        if(c_ptr==NULL){
            c_ptr=new CC();
            return c_ptr;
        }else return c_ptr;
    }
    int getValue(){return value_;}
    void setValue(int val){value_=val;}
    ~CC(){cout<<"~CC";}
private:
    CC():value_(12345){cout<<"CC";}
    static CC* c_ptr;
    int value_;
};
// Allocating and initializing CC's
// static data member.  The pointer is being
// allocated - not the object itself.
CC *CC::c_ptr = 0;

int main(){
    //Singleton pattern
    CC* myC = CC::cObj();
    cout<<myC->getValue();
    return 0;
}
```

> output: CC12345
>
> RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 67ms)

I noticed that indeed we can always declare singleton static instance within `shared_ptr` as with `boost::shared_ptr<CC> bCptr(CC::cObj());` but Singleton pattern doesn't mention the problem of deletion of the object at all so maybe there exists some other approach?

Comment: Who does singletons like this? Why not just return a `static CC`?

Comment: I seem to be missing the line where c_ptr is assigned a CC objecct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the Singleton design pattern is that it is indestructible.

EDIT:

There are 2 varieties of singletons with respect to destructibility:

1. Destructible (They die when the application does)
2. Indestructible (They die when the machine does)

Either way, if built properly, once the singleton instance is created, it stays.  This one of the major criticisms of the Singleton design pattern.

Here are a few references that address the destructibility aspect of the pattern.

http://nicolabonelli.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/singleton-a-mirage-of-perfection/
http://www10.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Teaching/Courses/SS2009/CPP/altmann.pdf
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/to_kill_a_singleton

Comment: I completely agree.  Let's bring that up on spacecraft.stackexchage.com

Comment: how it is indestructible? shouldn't it be called then Leak instead? is this the case that other apps may use it still however?

Comment: If a singleton leaked, then it wouldn't suitable to use as spacecraft material.

Comment: Singletons don't actually leak, because they remain firmly in place until the entire spacecraft or application is destroyed.

Comment: thanks, now I understand both spaceships and singleton deletion

Answer (score 4):

The classical singleton pattern does not describe the deletion aspect.

However, if I have to do it, I would start with a simple approach like the following (it is not fool-proof):

1) Similar to the static method for creating/retrieving the singleton object, say `createObject()`, there is a static method for destructing the singleton object, say `destructObject()`

2) There is a counter which counts the current number of objects in the system;

- it starts at 0
- on `createObject()` call, it increments by 1
- on `deleteObject()` call, it decrements by 1.

  - If it reaches 0, then the `delete` is called to *actually* destruct the object

Comment: only difference with shared_ptr is that the counter is global (in system not single app that use this singleton) right?

Comment: The counter is also singleton like the actual object.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to not use a pointer.

```
class Single
{
private:
   Single();

public:
   Single& Instance()
   {
      static Single the_instance;
      Return the_instance;
   }
};
```

This singleton will live from the time `Instance()` is called until the application is exiting and performing the destruction of static objects.  In this case the destructor of the singleton object will be called.

In practice, even when using a pointer as in the original example, the memory will be reclaimed by the OS upon application exit.  However in this case the object's destructor will *not* be called.